# Output of only question marks in Weka

Tags: weka

I'm trying to get predictions for a test set using a training set in Weka with the random forest algorithm. My issue is that the 'detailed accuracy by class' output shows only question marks (see the attached photo). Additionally, it seems like it's not recognizing the number of instances, as it says the total number of instances is 0.

Some additional info: the number and names of all my attributes on both the training and test .arff files match. I've also tried running just the training dataset using the cross-validation option in Weka with no problems. The issue is only occurring when I run the training set against the test set using the 'supplied test set' option in the Weka classify tab. I'm pretty new to Weka, so any advice is greatly appreciated!

[Weka issue photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud64W.jpg)

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with other datasets? E.g., you could split the iris UCI dataset and follow the same approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And yes, I tried following the instructions and using a test and training dataset provided on a university course page online (https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~ddowney/courses/349_Spring2017/pset1.html). I got the same results of all question marks for the detailed accuracy by class , making me think that it's something I'm doing incorrectly rather than an issue with my research data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this.

1. Use the *iris.arff* data set included with Weka to make the data set *iris without setosa.arff*  (i.e. just get rid of the setosa lines with a text editor). You're just doing this to easily get a test file that's different.
2. In Explorer Preprocess open *iris.arff*.
3. Move to the Classify tab and run a model, say J48. You will get the metrics from this model.
4. Now, click on Supplied test set, and tell it *iris without setosa.arff* is the test set.
5. If you also want the individual predictions, click on More options, and under Output Predictions change Null to CSV (which will put the predictions in CSV format you can copy to Excel).
6. Click start, and it will use the last model in memory to make predictions on this test set, and you will get the appropriate confusion matrix.

=

```
== Confusion Matrix ===

  a  b  c   <-- classified as
  0  0  0 |  a = Iris-setosa
  0 49  1 |  b = Iris-versicolor
  0  2 48 |  c = Iris-virginica
```

This example may help you see what you need to do to get the results you want.